# Bootstrap dataTable search and pagination is not working when data is loading from ajax API response

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I developing a admin panel. I am able to load data that is getting from Ajax API response in bootstrap `dataTable` but default search and pagination of the table is not working.
I tried

```
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true
```

to initialize the table but it is not working.

Is It possible this dataTable functionality work as default provided by the Bootstrap dataTable.

I want to achieve the following steps:

*Step1:* A form with submit button.

*Step2:* When clicked on submit, make an ajax call and get JSON Data back to add it into `dataTable` rows dynamically.

*Step3:*

```
         $("#editable-sample").DataTable({ // what should I do here.});
```

**Problem**

Data is loading but search box and pagination is not woking on the page.

Comment: if you put your code here, we can help you, really.

Comment: I think I am not able to initialize the dataTable

Comment: @hakkikonu, I'm sending the ajax request on submit button not inside the dataTable function.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code?

Are you sure you fulfilled the dataTables prerequisites:

1. The table must have `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags
2. The table must have an id that is used in the launch script example:

   `<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTables-example">
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
      });
   </script>`

Comment: Thanks. I did the same as you suggested but search and pagination is working but when  data is coming from api response these functionality is not working.

Comment: @RaghavSingh Then this must be related to initializationg try this:

var dataTable = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    dataTable = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/script-to-accept-request.php",
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "iDisplayLength": 50
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

datatables supports Ajax data source (objects), [see](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Below you can see an example which taken from dataTables' doc

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/objects.txt", //
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

AJAX

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But problem is that initially  dataTable is empty. Now there is small form basis on this form I am calling a API on submit form ajax call. Then I am parsing the json and loading the data in a dataTable row. Then Everything is working data is coming and loading into table but pagination and searching is not working. If I am typing something in to search box then table is going to empty.

Comment: so please put these sentences as code to your question. Without code many users can't know what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({..

 success: function(data) {..  

var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
table.clear().draw();
var rowNode= new Array();
for (var key=0, size=data.length; key<size; key++){
            var j = -1;
            var r = new Array();
// represent columns as array
                r[++j] ='<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="somename1" value="'+data[key].id+'"/><input type="hidden" name="somename2" value="'+data[key].is_deleted+'"/>'+data[key].lic_category_name+'</td>';
                r[++j] = '<td>'+data[key].someval1+'</td>';
                r[++j] = '<td>'+ data[key].someval2+'</td>';
                r[++j] = '<td>'+ data[key].someval13+ '</td>';
                r[++j] ='<td class="last"><a href="view?id='+data[key].id+' title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> <a href="edit?id='+data[key].id+'title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a href="delete?id='+data[key].id+'onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td></tr>'; 
                rowNode = table.row.add(r);

        }

        rowNode.draw().node()

   }
}
```

My JSON Response,

```
[{"id":70,"somekey1":"GC 1","somekey2":"GC 1","somekey3":8,"somekey4":5000,"somekey5":1,"somekey5":1,"is_deleted":0}]
```

It worked for me ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred  because of 'column' attribute try to match data row values with column before it get the data.
  so i place the close Curly bracket of 'ajax' attribute before 'column' attribute.
  now the column attribute function get call only after ajax function is complete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
    $('#example').DataTable( {            
        "ajax":{ "data/objects.txt" },//<------------------------------------------------place here//            
        "columns": [                                                              
            { "data": "name" },             
            { "data": "position" },         
            { "data": "office" },        
            { "data": "extn" },           
            { "data": "start_date" },          
            { "data": "salary" }         
        ]          
    });  
} );
```